# Performance difference on ST_DWithin between tables with similar size

Tags: postgis, spatial-join, performance

I am performing a spatial join between the left table (`at_test`) with about 1000 rows and two right tables (`sociodemo_filt` and `pb_poi_geog`) with about 5M rows each. 
I am working with geographies, and each table are indexed on this geography column. 
I observe a difference in performance of a factor 40 on the following query:

```
SELECT
    l.jdecode
FROM
    at_test as l left join
    (select the_geog from left_table) as s
on   ST_DWITHIN(l.the_geog, s.the_geog, 1000)
GROUP BY
        l.jdecode
```

When looking at the results of `analyze explain` I just notice a slight difference on `Index Scan`. The `pb_poi_geog` (the table for which the query takes much longer) has much more rows in the index scan (please see screenshots below). Why is that? And more importantly how can I achieve the same performance than for the table `sociodemo_filt`?

Query plan for sociodemo_filt (fast query)
[image]

Query plan for pb_poi_geog (slow query)
[image]

Comment: where is your join clause?

Comment: Thanks for pointing at this, I ve replaced the `where` by a `left join` clause in the code snippet to be consistant with the body of the question. Nevertheless, using `where` or `left join` lead to similar performances here

Comment: What kind of geometries are they? How complex?

Comment: I have simple geometries (or actually geographies), only points, irrespectively of the  table.

Comment: The datasets are not the same. In the 1st case only about 50,000 points are believed to be within the specified distance, while in the 2nd case it is about 3,250,000 points.

Comment: Make sure to `vacuum analyze` the 3 tables. Clustering the table using the spatial index may help a bit too (though not really if the distance is to be computed for 3/5 of the table anyways)

Comment: @JGH, thanks for the suggestions! Actually, I am not expecting to have such differences in terms of points within the specified distance between the 2 tables since both shall have a pretty uniform coverage of the region. Could this difference reveals a potential problem occuring during the index creation stage?

Comment: These numbers seems unrelated to the index. Try doing a count(*) instead of a group by to be sure. Of course this is assuming the query is the same as shown...

Comment: @JGH, thanks again! you put me on the right direction. There is indeed a big difference on the number of matches between the two spatial joins... probably explaining the difference on the execution time.